# How would I hyphenate the phrase "quaternary ammonium compound based?"?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing a scientific research paper, and in the abstract, I need to describe the substance that my team used in an experiment. The substance in question is a cleaner called Ster-BacⓇ Blu, and it contains a chemical belonging to a group of chemical compounds known as quaternary ammonium compounds. What I want to write is that "Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a [quaternary ammonium compound]-based liquid sanitizer." In other words, I'm saying that Ster-BacⓇ Blu is based on quaternary ammonium compounds. The problem is, I'm not sure how to hyphenate that.

Would I hyphenate that as

1. "quaternary ammonium compound-based?" or
2. "quaternary-ammonium-compound-based?" or
3. some other method of hyphenation that I don't know about?

Or, is it impossible to hyphenate such a long phrase, and would I have to reword it to something like "Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a liquid sanitizer based on a quaternary ammonium compound" instead?

Comment: There are lots of written instances of [***quaternary ammonium compound-based***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quaternary+ammonium+compound-based%22) in Google Books, and they're mostly hyphenated just like that (GB ignores punctuation marks, so all possibilities would be found with my search there).

Comment: The logical, pedantic form is probably << quaternary-ammonium-compound–based >> (the two hyphens showing the more cohesive adherences): << [[quaternary ammonium] compound]–based >>, **or** one might even perhaps argue for << quaternary-ammonium–compound—based >> (showing 3 levels of cohesiveness), << [[[quaternary ammonium] compound] based] >> ... but as the grouping is obvious to those likely to encounter the descriptor, a single hyphen in place of the en-dash is fine, less cluttered ... and seemingly usual.

Comment: Is there any reason you feel compelled to describe the compound in that manner, where attributive adjectives are stacked like rail cars with a caboose? What is wrong with saying "The liquid sanitizer, [product name], is based on a quaternary ammonium compound"?  That is perfectly grammatical.  Why do you think of it as inferior, as a Plan B?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That was my first thought (attributive, "fronted" usages should be *fully-hyphenated*). I was quite surprised to see that almost all the first two pages of GB results only hyphenated the *final* word-pair. But biochemists aren't necessarily the final authority on pedantic points of order.

Comment: As @TimR: "Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a liquid sanitizer based on quaternary ammonium compounds."

Comment: @FF But they're experts on bonding.

Comment: @TimR I don't necessarily think it's inferior. I suppose I felt that other parts of my research paper read like the latter, so I wanted to change things up. But I've ended up going with the version that requires no hyphenation. It's the simplest.

Comment: @TimR I hadn't read your suggestion when I composed my answer, but it doesn't really matter, because of the distinction between a comment and an answer. And I feel strongly enough on this to want to write an answer. I would have cited you in my answer but I have already on citation to the other answer, which takes priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you mentioned *quaternary ammonium compound(s)* prior to that sentence? If so, you could do this:

> *A sentence mentions quaternary ammonium compound (quat). Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a quat-based liquid sanitizer.*
>  or
> *A sentence mentions quaternary ammonium compounds (quats). Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a quats-based liquid sanitizer.*

If you haven’t mentioned *quaternary ammonium compound(s)* already, you could do this:

> *Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a quaternary ammonium compound (quat)-based liquid sanitizer.*
>  or
> *Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a quaternary ammonium compounds (quats)-based liquid sanitizer.*

Here are a few academic papers using the latter configuration:
<sub>[Interruption of Rotavirus Spread Through Chemical Disinfection](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/infection-control-and-hospital-epidemiology/article/abs/interruption-of-rotavirus-spread-through-chemical-disinfection/5131FFB3FB46F5F886730AF61AA6A49E)</sub>
<sub>[A model system for evaluating surface disinfection in dairy factory environments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168160509006229)</sub>
<sub>[Cellulose fibers modified with nano-sized antimicrobial polymer latex for pathogen deactivation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0144861715007870)</sub>

You can look for other ways to handle the situation wherever academics hang out, e.g. [scholar.google.com](https://scholar.google.com/) (though I would avoid emulating any that don’t use a hyphen or en dash in front of *based*).

By the way, *quat* is a full-fledged word in the *OED*:

> **quat** *noun<sup>3</sup>*
> *Chemistry.*
>  A quaternary ammonium cation or salt, esp. one used as a disinfectant, herbicide, or surfactant. Cf. **quaternary** *n.*
> A.4.
>  <sub>[selected citation]</sub>
>  <sub>**1970**  
> During the last 33 years, quaternary ammonium compounds (quats) have
> gained wide usage as germicides in industry.</sub>
>  <sub>Source:
> [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*Don’t!* Solve the problem underlying the question with a **preposition**:

> Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a liquid sanitizer **based on** a quaternary ammonium salt

(or whatever is the chemically preferred description to replace ‘compound’)

**Addressing the underlying question**

Some may frown at an answer of the type “Don’t do that, do something else”, but this is an English site, not a quiz site. The underlying problem is how to express clearly a concept or entity that by its technical nature is of a length that causes difficulty in making an unambiguous distinction between its components. In this case the composite structure of the chemical name can cause a false of misleading association with the description ‘based’.

The solution assumed by the poster is hyphenation, which works well in short phrases, e.g. *alcohol-based* cleanser, and is to be preferred to my suggestion if the phrase is repeated. In such a case I would adopt a *general version* of the specific solution offered by @TinfoilHat as:

*• Use an abbreviation for the chemical*. Where a pre-existing one does not exist, invent one (e.g. *NSAA-based* for non-standard amino acid ~ based) but be sure to define (and explain it) on first use.

**Use of Prepositions**

Beware of copying what you read in the scientific literature. Many scientists seem to regard prepositions as the new taboo words, and will go to any lengths to avoid adding a two-letter word to a sentence. In the example above the use of ‘on’ avoids a string of four words as the description of ‘sanitizer’ by dividing the sentence clearly into two parts. It also means that the reader does not have to wait until the end of the sentence to find out that Ster-BacⓇ Blu is a sanitizer.

The other neglected preposition is **of**. Compare:

> water-conserving functions **of** the rectal complex **in** *Tribolium
> castaneum*

and

> *Tribolium castaneum* rectal complex water-conserving functions

(I would provide a reference for this, but I’m too modest.)